# Unable to install xampp in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, apache2, sudo

I am installing xampp in ubuntu 13.04, but while installing the xampp..

when i try to extract the file .. it shows the following message

```
               sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz -C /opt
```

The response is as follows..

```
      tar (child): xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
      tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
      tar: Child returned status 2
      tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How to get rid of the error.

Comment: "No such file or directory" seems there is no "xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz" file in /opt, so make sure you are using the right path.

Comment: So it means, I need the opt folder which contains the "xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz".... right..

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen It's working now.....

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2155833 Use package manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know from where you have got that package. But XAMP have a very easy of installing. open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then paste these lines one after one flawlessly.

**For 32-Bit Ubuntu**

```
wget http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-linux-1.8.3-1-installer.run
chmod +x xampp-linux-1.8.3-1-installer.run
./xampp-linux-1.8.3-1-installer.run
```

**For 64-Bit Ubuntu**

```
wget http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
```

After installing to start XAMP type the command as

```
 /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Then check your browser with  `http://localhost` for proper installation verification.

Comment: I downloaded that from Soureforge.net.... it worked previously, but now it's not working and showing the above message...

Comment: Ok now follow my answer, I am sure that going to help you.

Comment: ok... i will follow it...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand where you got that but here's how you install it:

1) Add the ppa:

```
 $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/xampp
```

2) Update the repo index:

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
```

3) Install XAMPP:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install xampp
```

Have fun, comment below if you have any issues. I'd love to hep you if so.

Comment: c'mon shaun I am helping you my dear friend. the format you have mentioned is not proper for code.

Comment: @rajagenupula Thanks for the edit -:) I'm new to the community. *Edit: My bad, sorry.

Comment: Its ok my friend , :)

Comment: I got confused by 12.04 and 13.04, aha!