# cannot access ‘xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run’: No such file or directory

Tags: installation, 64-bit, apache2, php, lamp

I am a complete novice with Linux Ubuntu. When installing xampp it occurs to me this message:

```
Can not access 'xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run': No such file or directory
```

I followed these instructions to install:

For 64-Bit Ubuntu

```
wget http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run

chmod + x xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run

./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
```

on this page: [Unable to install xampp in ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339641/unable-to-install-xampp-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Thanks for the help

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste as it is , the mistake you have done space between + and x at chmod.

the right way is,

```
wget http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
```

EDIT:

Now actually your file was saved to `download.php?xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run.1` , so now in the terminal paste as `mv download.php?xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run.1 xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run` and then run the remaining commands.

Comment: chmod: cannot access ‘xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run’: No such file or directory

Comment: Same message after I typed second line ...

Comment: could you give me complete log of your terminal ?

Comment: Stupid question ... Where is terminal log?

Comment: @user215723 please talk nicely. Terminal log means how you are doing the method , copy it and paste in ubuntu.pastebin.com and give me link here.

Comment: Excuse my expression. I had no intention offending you ...

Comment: here is link : http://pastebin.com/XX809d84

Comment: @Ales71 sorry for the delay. Now actually your file was saved to download.php?xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run.1 , so now in the terminal paste as ` mv download.php?xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run.1 xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-1-installer.run
` and then run the remaining commands.

Comment: No problem :-) Worked but I have now new message : This installer requers root privileges. Please become superuser before executing the installer

Comment: Solved problem with superuser. Because people like you can say : goodbye windows forever